# “Je lui crois” or “je crois à lui”

Tags: prépositions, verbes

Why doesn't “croire à” follow the same construction as for example “téléphoner à”? I've seen it written

> Je crois à lui

But I would write

> Je lui crois.

just like

> Je lui téléphone

I know there are exception, most notably

> Je pense à lui.

However I can't find “croire à” in this group of exceptions.

Merci.

Comment: You should say: "Je crois **en** lui" ou "je **le** crois"

Comment: @Toto "Je crois en lui" being "I believe **in** him" and "Je le crois"  "I believe him"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ce ne peut pas être "Je crois en lui" dans ce cas, car "croire à" et "croire en" ont des sens très différents. "Je crois en lui" signifie que j'ai confiance dans ses capacités, j'ai foi en sa réussite future. Ce n'est évidemment pas ce qu'on veut dire en parlant du père Noël.

La forme "je crois à lui" est également impossible dans tous les cas, parce qu'on ne dit pas "croire à quelqu'un" (ça n'a aucun sens en français). Pourtant, on dit bien "croire au Père Noël"... oui, mais dans ce cas, en réalité, on sous-entend un COI : c'est croire à l'EXISTENCE DU Père Noël.

C'est pourquoi il faut soit rétablir le complément sous-entendu ("Je crois à son existence"), soit employer le pronom renvoyant à "existence" : "y", mis pour un complément indirect désignant un inanimé :
"Le Père Noël, oui, j'y crois encore!" (=je crois encore à son existence)

Comment: La question de Mumfi ne mentionne pas le Père Noël.

Comment: @jlliagre la question ne mentionne pas du tout le nom qui est remplacé par "lui". Je trouve intéressant que l'on dise "croire au Père Noël, aux fées" et "croire en Dieu" --> y croire alors que la construction "à + le Père Noël" pourrait laisser croire que "croire à lui" est correct. Bien entendu, la réponse à la question est sans doute "le croire".

Answer (score 3):

*Croire* can be followed by a direct object or an indirect object.

When followed by an indirect object, this object can be introduced by either the preposition *à* or the preposition *en* according to what meaning *croire* has. 
English does not make the difference and uses "in" in both cases.

*Croire **à*** means to be persuaded in the veracity, the efficiency or the existence of something. it is never followed by a person's name or a pronoun representing a person.

> Je ne crois pas aux fantômes. (aux = à les)
>   *I don't believe in ghosts.*
>
> Je crois à la parole de Dieu.
>   *I believe in the word of God*.

*Croire **en*** means to have faith in someone or something and to behave accordingly. It is a spiritual attitude, it can be a sign of love.

> Je crois en Dieu.
>   *I believe in God*.
>
> Je crois en elle et je sais qu'elle va réussir.
>   *I believe in her and I know she will succed*.

When *croire* is followed by a direct object, that is to say when the complement is not introduced by a preposition, it has the same meaning as the English "believe someone", used also without a preposition.

> Je le crois.
>   *I believe him.*

<strike>Je lui crois.</strike> is impossible. You can only use *lui* with *croire en*.

Comment: The affirmation that "croire à" cannot be used with a person is not completely true. What about "croire à Père Noël" ? If you meant a real (non-fictitious) person there, please make it clear in the answer. It's also relevant to mention that "croire à" can be used with a group of people (eg médecins, astrologues).

Comment: @AlanEvangelista *Le Père Noël* is not a person's name, you must use use a definite article before *Père Noël*, it is *croire au Père Noël*. Exactly the same example as the one I used with *fantômes*, it means you believe Santa exists, it is doesn't mean you believe him.  Same if you say *je crois aux médecins* (which means you believe doctors exist) *médecin* is not a person's name.